# Get cross reference model

Tags: python, peewee

I am having trouble accessing the cross-reference (through) model in my code.

As you can see by the code below, I have a field in my cross reference model that I would like to select through the SoundFile model, but I can't seem to figure out how.

I am new to python and peewee, so please bear with me. I have programming experience, just not python. I would appreciate any help you can offer.

**A little lay of the land:**
I have a repository that keeps in memory a list of the SoundFile records. I am looping through those records and trying to get access to the cross-reference model (for the field in that model). The BaseModel that each model extends just sets up the Class Meta.

SoundFile Model

```
from peewee import *
from OgmaChatBot.entities.BaseModel import BaseModel


class SoundFile(BaseModel):
    file_name = TextField()
    short_name = TextField()
    command_available = IntegerField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT 0")])

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        return SoundFile.select()

    @staticmethod
    def get_one(key):
        return SoundFile.get(SoundFile.id == key)
```

Event Model

```
from peewee import *
from OgmaChatBot.entities.BaseModel import BaseModel


class Event(BaseModel):
    event = TextField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        return Event.select()

    @staticmethod
    def get_one(key):
        return Event.get(Event.id == key)
```

SoundEvent Model (cross reference model)

```
from peewee import *
from OgmaChatBot.entities.BaseModel import BaseModel
from OgmaChatBot.entities.Event import Event
from OgmaChatBot.entities.SoundFile import SoundFile


class SoundEvent(BaseModel):
    sound_file = ForeignKeyField(
        column_name='sound_file_id',
        field='id',
        model=SoundFile,
        backref='sound_event'
    )
    event = ForeignKeyField(
        column_name='event_id', 
        field='id', 
        model=Event, 
        backref='sound_event'
    )
    username = TextField(null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        query = (SoundEvent
                 .select(SoundEvent, SoundFile, Event)
                 .join(SoundFile)
                 .switch(SoundEvent)
                 .join(Event))

        return query

    @staticmethod
    def get_one(key):
        query = (SoundEvent
                 .select()
                 .join(SoundFile)
                 .switch(SoundEvent)
                 .join(Event)
                 .where(SoundEvent.id == key))

        return query
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't clear what you are trying to do...but here are some examples based on the staticmethod you shared:

```
@staticmethod
def get_all():
    query = (SoundEvent
             .select(SoundEvent, SoundFile, Event)
             .join(SoundFile)
             .switch(SoundEvent)
             .join(Event))

    return query
```

Then you could print all filenames:

```
for sound_event in SoundEvent.get_all():
    print(sound_event.sound_file.filename)
```

Or to print all events:

```
for sound_event in SoundEvent.get_all():
    print(sound_event.event.event)
```

Alternatively, you could also go from a `SoundFile` and list all events:

```
sound_file = SoundFile.get(SoundFile.filename == 'the-file.mp3')
events = (Event
          .select()
          .join(SoundEvent)
          .where(SoundEvent.sound_file == sound_file))
for event in events:
    print(event.event)
```

Equivalent with two joins instead:

```
events = (Event
          .select()
          .join(SoundEvent)
          .join(SoundFile)
          .where(SoundFile.filename == 'the-file.mp3'))
for event in events:
    print(event.event)
```

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't very clear. What I am trying to do is get access to the username field in the SoundEvent model, starting from the SoundFile model. In my repository, I have a list of SoundFile objects. I am looping through them, and in each iteration, I would like to get the username associated with the relationship. Does that make a little more sense?

Answer (score -1):

Based on comments from the OP:

> What I am trying to do is get access to the username field in the SoundEvent model, starting from the SoundFile model. In my repository, I have a list of SoundFile objects.

There are two ways. Since there may be 0..n SoundEvent objects per sound-file, we'll do this:

```
for sound_file in sound_files:
    events = (SoundEvent
              .select(SoundEvent.username)
              .where(SoundEvent.sound_file == sound_file))
    print(sound_file.filename)
    for event in events:
        print(' * ', event.username)
```

Since you have declared the SoundEvent.sound_file foreign-key with `backref="sound_event"`, you can also do this, which is equivalent (though consider making backref sound_events plural):

```
for sound_file in sound_files:
    print(sound_file.filename)
    for event in sound_file.sound_event:
        print(' * ', event.username)
```

A final option is to try and do this more efficiently using `prefetch()`, which is a bit more complicated in its implementation, and should only be used after profiling:

```
sound_files_with_events = prefetch(sound_files, SoundEvent)
for sound_file in sound_files_with_events:
    print(sound_file.filename)
    for event in sound_file.sound_event:  # the backref is pre-populated!
        print(' * ', event.username)
```